# Hosting 2 sites on the same IP - IIS on 80, Apache on 8080

Tags: apache, iis, ports

I found this and followed the link in the answer, but i'm not sure if i'm getting it.
[Redirect domain IIS to Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246462/redirect-domain-iis-to-apache)

so i have a server running IIS listening to port 80 and a site "domain.com" on that setup.  i created a subdomain "sub.domain.com" with Wordpress running on WAMP.  i have WAMPs Apache listening to 8080 and i can see my site with localhost:8080/wordpress, so it seems like that's all working.

now, how do i route incoming traffic to one or the other? traffic for "www.domain.com" should go to IIS on 80, and traffic for "sub.domain.com" should go to Apache on 8080.

Is this even possible?  (i also created an A record for "sub.domain.com" to point to the same IP as "www.domain.com" which is the IP of our webserver, so that's also taken care of)

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You might check the apache documentation here regarding "Running different sites on different ports.": http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: You need to set up an IIS reverse proxy to route requests Apache can fulfill to the port it's running on.

Comment: SLoW, i was looking at that page, "Running different sites on different ports." and, looking at the virtualhosts stuff, it seems like this applies to Apache handling multiple sites.  My problem is that (i think) i need to tell IIS about my virtual host so it can throw anything requesting "sub.domain.com" to Apache.  I think SamT's reply might be where i need to be.  which is this site:  http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/archive/2010/04/01/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx

Comment: oops, that should have been this link:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2010/04/02/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx

I think i'll try poking around with this.